# Grepping a 20g file in bash

Tags: regex, performance, bash, unix, grep

Question about code performance: I'm trying to run ~25 regex rules against a ~20g text file. The script should output matches to text files; each regex rule generates its own file. See the pseudocode below:

```
regex_rules=~/Documents/rulesfiles/regexrulefile.txt
for tmp in *.unique20gbfile.suffix; do
    while read line
    # Each $line in the looped-through file contains a regex rule, e.g.,
    # egrep -i '(^| )justin ?bieber|(^| )selena ?gomez'
    # $rname is a unique rule name generated by a separate bash function
    # exported to the current shell.
        do
        cmd="$line $tmp > ~/outputdir/$tmp.$rname.filter.piped &"
        eval $cmd
    done < $regex_rules
done
```

Couple thoughts:

- Is there a way to loop the text file just once, evaluating all rules and splitting to individual files in one go? Would this be faster?
- Is there a different tool I should be using for this job?

Thanks.

Comment: What's in the regexrulefile.txt?

Comment: Thanks, sorry: It's a file of regex rules. So each line contains a rule like 'egrep -i '(^| )justin ?bieber|(^| )selena ?gomez'

Comment: So each line in the regex file maps to a different output file?

Comment: Are `file` and `tmp` intended to be the same variable? Otherwise, `file` is unused and `tmp` is an unknown

Comment: Yeah. So egrep -i 'foo' outputs to ~/outputdir/$tmp.foo.filter.piped. And chepner, yes, sorry typo. Fixing...

Comment: Could you read the file line by line and echo it to each command?

Comment: Yeah, I think I could. Would that be faster?

Comment: I would probably hack up a quick solution in Perl to avoid some shell overhead and to avoid external tools ... grepping through 20gb will be slow either way.

Comment: @amon Perl is most definitely the way to go on this.

Comment: @amon: Agreed. In my experience, even with very simple regexes, `perl -ne 'print if m/.../' < input > output` is much faster than `grep '...' < input > output`. I don't know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the reason `grep` has a `-f` option. Reduce your `regexrulefile.txt` to just the regexps, one per line, and run

```
egrep -f regexrulefile.txt the_big_file
```

This produces all the matches in a single output stream, but you can do your loop thing on it afterward to separate them out. Assuming the combined list of matches isn't huge, this will be a performance win.

Comment: Got it. I was going to ask about separating the output. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A quick (!= too fast) Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
```

We preload regexes so that we read their files only once. They are stored in the array `@regex`. The regex file is the first file given as argument.

```
open REGEXES, '<', shift(@ARGV) or die;
my @regex = map {qr/$_/} <REGEXES>;
# use the following if the file still includes the egrep:
# my @regex = map {
#     s/^egrep \s+ -i \s+ '? (.*?) '? \s* $/$1/x;
#     qr{$_}
# } <REGEXES>;
close REGEXES or die;
```

We go through each remaining file that was given as argument:

```
while (@ARGV) {
  my $filename = shift @ARGV;
```

We pre-open files for efficiency:

```
  my @outfile = map {
     open my $fh, '>', "outdir/$filename.$_.filter.piped"
       or die "Couldn't open outfile for $filename, rule #$_";
     $fh;
  } (1 .. scalar(@rule));
  open BIGFILE, '<', $filename or die;
```

We print all lines that match a rule to the specified file.

```
  while (not eof BIGFILE) {
    my $line = <BIGFILE>;
    for $ruleNo (0..$#regex) {
      print $outfile[$ruleNo] $line if $line =~ $regex[$ruleNo];
      # if only the first match is interesting:
      # if ($line =~ $regex[$ruleNo]) {
      #     print $outfile[$ruleNo] $line;
      #     last;
      # }
    }
  }
```

Cleaning up before the next iteration:

```
  foreach (@outfile) {
    close $_ or die;
  }
  close BIGFILE or die;
}

print "Done";
```

Invocation: `$ perl ultragrepper.pl regexFile bigFile1 bigFile2 bigFile3` etc. Anything quicker would have to be written directly in C. Your hard-disk data transfer speed is the limit.

This should run quicker as the bash pendant because I avoid re-opening files or reparsing regexes. Plus, no new processes have to be spawned for external tools. But we could spawn several threads! (at least NumOfProcessors * 2 threads may be sensible)

```
local $SIG{CHLD} = undef;
while (@ARGV) {
    next if fork();
    ...;
    last;
}
```

Comment: Once one of the regexes matches a line, do you care whether other regexes also match?  If not, you can use `last` to terminate the loop on the first match.

Comment: Yes -- if a two regexes match a line, the line should appear in both corresponding regex output files.

Comment: And thanks, amon, for the answer. Working through everything that's been presented here, will look forward to spending time with your code.

Comment: `1..@array` is not the correct set of indexes for an array. It should be `0..$#array`.

Comment: @tripleee (1) *"Wouldn't it be a lot faster"* — I don't think so. I'd be creating the same # of outfiles with the same # of calls to `open` / `close`. The algorithm would still be *O(n×m×o)* (2) I like declaring anything as late as possible. For many  infiles and many rules this also saves memory ;-) (3) *"You could end up with some empty files"* — This is part of my specification: If a rule doesn't match in a file, there has to be an empty file to symbolize that. (4) *"you could run out of file handles"* — The systemwide # of open FHs is more limited than the # of FHs closed by my process.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code; I mistakenly thought the open/close calls were inside `while(<BIGFILE>)` but obviously they're not. I'll remove my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar with `lex`. Of course, it runs every other day, so YMMV. It is very fast, even on several hundred megabyte files on a remote windows share. It takes only a few seconds to process. I don't know how comfortable you are hacking up a quick `C` program, but I've found this to be the fastest, easiest solution for large scale regex problems.

Parts redacted to protect the guilty:

```
    /************************************************** 
        start of definitions section

    ***************************************************/


%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <errno.h>

char inputName[256];
// static insert variables

//other variables
char tempString[256];
char myHolder[256];
char fileName[256];
char unknownFileName[256];
char stuffFileName[256];
char buffer[5];

/* we are using pointers to hold the file locations, and allow us to dynamically open and close new files */
/* also, it allows us to obfuscate which file we are writing to, otherwise this couldn't be done */

FILE *yyTemp;
FILE *yyUnknown;
FILE *yyStuff;

// flags for command line options
static int help_flag = 0;

%}

%option 8bit 
%option nounput nomain noyywrap 
%option warn

%%
    /************************************************ 
        start of rules section
    *************************************************/


(\"A\",\"(1330|1005|1410|1170)\") { 
    strcat(myHolder, yytext);
    yyTemp = &(*yyStuff);
} //stuff files

. { strcat(myHolder, yytext); }

\n  {
    if (&(*yyTemp) == &(*yyUnknown))
        unknownCount += 1;
    strcat(myHolder, yytext); 
    //print to file we are pointing at, whatever it is
    fprintf(yyTemp, "%s", myHolder);
    strcpy(myHolder, "");
    yyTemp = &(*yyUnknown);
}

<<EOF>> {
    strcat(myHolder, yytext); 
    fprintf(yyTemp, "%s", myHolder);
    strcpy(myHolder, "");
    yyTemp = &(*yyUnknown);

    yyterminate();
}

%%
    /**************************************************** 
        start of code section


    *****************************************************/


int main(int argc, char **argv);

int main (argc,argv)
int argc;
char **argv;
{
    /****************************************************
        The main method drives the program. It gets the filename from the
        command line, and opens the initial files to write to. Then it calls the lexer.
        After the lexer returns, the main method finishes out the report file,
        closes all of the open files, and prints out to the command line to let the
        user know it is finished.
    ****************************************************/

    int c;

    // the gnu getopt library is used to parse the command line for flags
    // afterwards, the final option is assumed to be the input file

    while (1) {
        static struct option long_options[] = {
            /* These options set a flag. */
            {"help",   no_argument,     &help_flag, 1},
            /* These options don't set a flag. We distinguish them by their indices. */
            {0, 0, 0, 0}
        };
           /* getopt_long stores the option index here. */
        int option_index = 0;
        c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "h",
            long_options, &option_index);

        /* Detect the end of the options. */
        if (c == -1)
            break;

        switch (c) {
            case 0:
               /* If this option set a flag, do nothing else now. */
               if (long_options[option_index].flag != 0)
                 break;
               printf ("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
               if (optarg)
                 printf (" with arg %s", optarg);
               printf ("\n");
               break;

            case 'h':
                help_flag = 1;
                break;

            case '?':
               /* getopt_long already printed an error message. */
               break;

            default:
               abort ();
            }
    }

    if (help_flag == 1) {
        printf("proper syntax is: yourProgram.exe [OPTIONS]... INFILE\n");
        printf("splits csv file into multiple files")
        printf("Option list: \n");
        printf("--help                  print help to screen\n");
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //get the filename off the command line and redirect it to input
    //if there is no filename then use stdin

    if (optind < argc) {
        FILE *file;

        file = fopen(argv[optind], "r");
        if (!file) {
            fprintf (stderr, "%s: Couldn't open file %s; %s\n", argv[0], argv[optind], strerror (errno));
            exit(errno);
        }
        yyin = file;
        strcpy(inputName, argv[optind]);
    }
    else {
        printf("no input file set, using stdin. Press ctrl-c to quit");
        yyin = stdin;
        strcpy(inputName, "\b\b\b\b\bagainst stdin");
    }

    //set up initial file names

    strcpy(fileName, inputName);
    strncpy(unknownFileName, fileName, strlen(fileName)-4);
    strncpy(stuffFileName, fileName, strlen(fileName)-4);

    strcat(unknownFileName, "_UNKNOWN_1.csv");
    strcat(stuffFileName, "_STUFF_1.csv");

    //open files for writing

    yyout = stdout;
    yyTemp = malloc(sizeof(FILE));
    yyUnknown = fopen(unknownFileName,"w");
    yyTemp = &(*yyUnknown);

    yyStuff = fopen(stuffFileName,"w");

    yylex();

    //close open files

    fclose(yyUnknown);

    printf("Lexer finished running %s",fileName);

    return 0;

}
```

To build this flex program, have flex installed, and use this makefile (adjust the paths):

```
TARGET = project.exe
TESTBUILD = project
LEX = flex
LFLAGS = -Cf
CC = i586-mingw32msvc-gcc
CFLAGS = -O -Wall 
INSTALLDIR = /mnt/J/Systems/executables

.PHONY: default all clean install uninstall cleanall

default: $(TARGET)

all: default install

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.l, %.c, $(wildcard *.l))

%.c: %.l
    $(LEX) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $<

.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@

linux: $(OBJECTS)
    gcc $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) -lm -g -o $(TESTBUILD)

cleanall: clean uninstall

clean:
    -rm -f *.c
    -rm -f $(TARGET)
    -rm -f $(TESTBUILD)

uninstall:
    -rm -f $(INSTALLDIR)/$(TARGET)

install:
    cp -f $(TARGET) $(INSTALLDIR)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the structure: read the file in, then loop over the rules so you only perform matchs on  individual lines.

```
regex_rules=~/Documents/rulesfiles/regexrulefile.txt
for tmp in *.unique20gbfile.suffix; do
while read line ; do 
 while read rule
    # Each $line in the looped-through file contains a regex rule, e.g.,
    # egrep -i '(^| )justin ?bieber|(^| )selena ?gomez'
    # $rname is a unique rule name generated by a separate bash function
    # exported to the current shell.
        do
        cmd=" echo $line  | $rule  >> ~/outputdir/$tmp.$rname.filter.piped &"
        eval $cmd
    done < $regex_rules
done < $tmp
```

done

At this point though you could/should use bash (or perl's) built-in regex matching rather than have it fire up a separate egrep process for each match. You  might also be able to split the file 
and run parallel processes. (Note I also corrected > to >>)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not following, but that looks like three 'do' statements and two 'done' statements. Should the suggested code conclude ... done < $regex_rules \n done < $tmp \n done?

Comment: @tallus, thanks for your great ideas; I incorporated some (parallelism, built-ins) into my Perl answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also decided to come back here and write a perl version, before noticing that amon had already done it. Since it's already written, here's mine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -W
use strict;

# The search spec file consists of lines arranged in pairs like this:
# file1
# [Ff]oo
# file2
# [Bb]ar
# The first line of each pair is an output file. The second line is a perl
# regular expression. Every line of the input file is tested against all of
# the regular expressions, so an input line can end up in more than one
# output file if it matches more than one of them.

sub usage
{
        die "Usage: $0 search_spec_file [inputfile...]\n";
}

@ARGV or usage();

my @spec;

my $specfile = shift();
open my $spec, '<', $specfile or die "$specfile: $!\n";
while(<$spec>) {
        chomp;
        my $outfile = $_;
        my $regexp = <$spec>;
        chomp $regexp;
        defined($regexp) or die "$specfile: Invalid: Odd number of lines\n";
        open my $out, '>', $outfile or die "$outfile: $!\n";
        push @spec, [$out, qr/$regexp/];
}
close $spec;

while(<>) {
        for my $spec (@spec) {
                my ($out, $regexp) = @$spec;
                print $out $_ if /$regexp/;
        }
}
```